# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, specific-question, closed-questions

This question: [Single quotes vs. double quotes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python) was closed as not constructive. I wanted to know why, to better understand the seemingly obscure rules of SO.

Many questions I find in Google search are closed for no good reason, despite being the most popular questions on the site. Some of them are clearly asking for debate, and are closed, despite becoming great collections of information. The others are a mystery to me. This one was especially confusing.

Comment: Let me turn this back at you.... does it need to be open?  Is there anything that is not contained in one of the 19 answers that would need to be added as another answer?

Comment: No. I think the answers are complete. I even see why someone would want to close it to protect it from ruin (although personally I think closing any active discussion is tyranical), but I don't see how the stated reason applies to this question. If it was closed because it was "done" then I wouldn't be confused, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: It was closed because it wasn't constructive. It's not a real question, this is a Q&A site not a forum.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Why are popular question like these closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184353)

Comment: @bjb568 That's a BS reason and you know that as well as I do.

Comment: "That's a BS reason" is a BS reason for reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't have voted to close it, but I can understand why it was closed.

The question as-is was just a general question asking if there was a specific reason to choose `X over Y`.  The "not constructive" close reason was depreciated almost a year ago, but under the current guidelines, it could have been closed as "primarily opinion based" since answers would have been based on nothing more than someone's opinion as to which was correct.

You have to realize that the question was asked as such as time when question of that nature were perfectly acceptable, and were welcome.  But as Stack Overflow matured, we realized that some questions just simply don't work well in this format, for various reasons.  As such, they have been declared off-topic after the fact.

This exact question, if asked today, would have been heavily downvoted and closed quickly.

However, a closed question doesn't really mean much when the existing answers are good and complete.  The question itself is still visible, as are the answers.  All closing does is prevent new answers, and this question does not appear to need any new answers as the existing answers look to be complete.

Comment: s/depreciated/deprecated/?

Answer (score 4):

> closing any active discussion is tyranical *[sic]*

SO isn't a place for arbitrary discussion, no matter how scintillating. The discussion must fall within the remit of the site.

> Many questions I find in Google search are closed for no good reason, despite being the most popular questions on the site

Popularity != Relevance

It's for a similar reason that most paid jobs don't allow you to spend your whole day at work playing Starcraft. Would some employees want to do that? Sure! But if it were allowed the office would cease to be a useful resource. Occasional Starcraft is good for morale; frequent Starcraft means no transaction processing gets done.

By the same token, SO is for *specific* coding-relating questions / issues which arise from practical concerns. Stylistic questions- while certainly relevant to programmers generally and, I would argue, important to consider- don't fall under the umbrella of what SO is for.

Which isn't to say that it's not a good question in the general case, simply that it makes users who have immediate technical issues sift through more information on SO to find what they want.

Comment: Personally, I believe closing any active discussion, anywhere, by any means, is tyrannical as it restricts one of the most basic freedoms: freedom of speech. As I said though, that is just my opinion, and I understand that SO does not agree.

Comment: And as for the closed popular questions, the questions are popular because many people benefited from them in the first place. Is not the goal of SO to let people ask questions and benefit from the answers?

Comment: Sure- which is why good questions that aren't strictly relevant are closed, rather than deleted outright. People can still access the information, while posting further questions in the same style is discouraged. No one's preventing you from having a discussion; they're just saying SO isn't the place for that discussion. For the same reason you can't hold a political rally in a 7-11, you can't have fruitful discussion about arbitrary topics on SO. There are other, better places.