# Why o why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, scope

This question got closed three years after it was asked.  It has several answers.  I noticed the closing because I got a downvote for my answer.

[How to copy a table schema and constraints to a table of different database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600172/how-to-copy-a-table-schema-and-constraints-to-a-table-of-different-database)

> I need an sql which will copy schema of a specified table to a table
>   in different db.
>
> How to implement this?
>
> Please help.

The question is perhaps not well written, but it's plainly on topic. There's a lot of voting and answering activity, and it has an accepted answer.  None of the answers show any confusion as to what the question is about.

So why was this question closed as off-topic?

Comment: @Payeli The system does not allow duplicate titles. There is already an [existing question with the same title](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258563/why-was-this-question-closed) here.

Comment: Let's not start adding (2) to titles, I really don't think we need _Why was this question closed (100)?_ just to get around the duplicate title issue.

Comment: @bluefeet: except that it was not deleted before this post.  It got deleted in response to it being mentioned on meta.

Comment: @Andomar Ah ok, then use a title that makes this distinct instead of adding (2), etc.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know what kind of answer you are looking for....

By just looking at the gray box you get your "question" answered.

What is it that you don't understand here?

[image]

The big red **`NO`** may also need clarification.

Remember the golden (aka. *anti-repwhoring!*):

**If a question deserves to be closed then vote to close it. Do not answer it.**

By choosing to answer you're putting yourself at a risk of having your answer downvoted and deleted. Off-topic questions which fall in the -off-topic- category in the help-centre are simply OFF-TOPIC... they need to be downvoted, closed and deleted not answered.

BTW.

According to the [**help-centre**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) this question still, is **off-topic** as per no. 3

> `3`. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: Or you may have forgotten the fact that the question was answered almost 5 years ago, at which time it was perfectly on topic. Claiming that the OP chose to answer a question that deserves to be closed and thus put himself at risk for rep-whoring is a bit of a stretch here.

Comment: I was not sure how anyone could categorise this as off-topic.  The questioner is clearly aware of what he wants to do: copy a table schema.  Asking for "attempted results" or example output would not at all improve the question.  But I guess from your answer it has something to do with the questioner being judged unworthy of repution?

Comment: It does not matter when the question was asked or answered. If it's off-topic today then we vote to close it as off-topic. This is exactly why this site stays up to date and is much easier to navigate through than any other site because it's **moderated** and 90% of useless junk at some point does get deleted.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly this question does not meet SO quality - so closed with generic reason. Note that it have no delete votes - so will not magically disappear - just no new answers.

If you feel that it is good question - edit it the question to match answers and meet SO quality bar.

It looks like people find it from time to time, so effort may be well spend. OP unlikely to care and updated question will show visitors how good question should look like.

Comment: "Note that it have no delete votes - so will not magically disappear" BOOM meta effect ;)

Comment: For me it already meets the quality standards.  It's certainly better than half of new questions I see in the SQL tag today.  [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382736/give-the-sql-query-for-below-scenario) is fairly typical.  None of these questions gets closed or deleted.

Comment: @Andomar Consider re-learning what the quality standards are then - the question you're talking about doesn't even come close to being good enough for SO (btw the "typical" question you linked to in your previous comment was deleted within 15 minutes...)

Comment: @Clive: I guess nowadays people ask for a lot of formalities, like formatting, a lengthy body in proper English, thought out titles, no "pleae help" notes, and so on.  But materially this question is fine.

Comment: Nope. What you call 'formalities' are what we call 'requirements for an acceptable question'. Please familiarise yourself with all the literature in the help center on Stack Overflow to understand what's wrong with that question, there's far too much wrong to explain in a single comment (and since the information is already easily accessible I'm reluctant to repeat it for you here)

Answer (score 0):

## Close, but not delete

I completely agree with closing the question, but deletion is a different thing. The question had **6 answers**, 5 of them **upvoted**. Having deleted the question, we have deleted the answers, too, and if upvotes indicate merit to any extent, we have **deleted valuable content**.

I don't think we want to do that.

Comment: Well, somebody did; the question is gone. It is a good reflection of why I, and I suspect an increasing number of people, spend a diminishing amount of time on Stack Exchange. When it comes to dingbat ideas about ideological "purity" of questions vs the actual utility to end users, moderation on this site increasingly leans toward the former. Note also the 11 (formerly 12) downvotes for the questioner daring to question this purity.